# Problem with API calling particular document

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Short summary: SPA with basic CRUD, get a task list and view/delete/modify it.

So I have this particular two bits of code for my project. One is to display all tasks, and another is to display a particular task by its title name.

```
getTask = () => {
fetch("/api/getTask", )
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => this.setState({ task: data.task, isLoading: false }))
  .catch(error => this.setState({error, isLoading: false}));
};


updateTaskWindow = title => {

this.setState({ isUpdating: true });
this.setState({ title: title});
fetch("/api/getSingleTask", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    title : this.state.title
  })
}, )
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => this.setState({ task: data.task, isLoading: false, 
 isUpdating: true }))
  .catch(error => this.setState({error, isLoading: false}));
};
```

This "getTask" renders out fine and gets me a list of tasks I've previously submitted.

Here are my API Calls, for reference.

```
router.get("/getTask", (req, res) => {
  Task.find((err, task) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err });
      return res.json({ success: true, task: task });
  });
});

router.post("/getSingleTask", (req, res) => {
  const { title } = req.body
  Task.find( {title: {$eq: title}}, (err, task) => {
    if (err) return res.json({ success: false, error: err});
      return res.json({ success:true, task:task})
  })
});
```

Basic idea: when press on "Update" button, it instead should render a new task window, but with input elements instead of simply paragraphs.

The problem is that when I try to press "Update" button on my task list, it returns a blank page. After numerous tries of getting the correct code for API, this is just getting frustrating.

Matter of fact is, if I put a particular string in my API call (say, put `test` instead of `title`), then it returns me a window of a single task which had that particular title just as I want it. If I put the variable reference back, it renders a blank page. And yes, all API calls work fine.

My rendering code below

```
render() {

const { isUpdating, isLoading, error, task } = this.state;
return (
  <div>
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Task list</h1>
      {error ? <p>{error.message}</p> : null}
      {!isLoading ? ( 
        !isUpdating ?  ( task.map(item => {
          const { title, description, createdDate, updatedDate, isCompleted } = item;
          return (
            <div style={{ width: '50%', margin: 'auto'}} key={title}>
              <p>Title: {title}</p>
              <p>Desc: {description}</p>
              <p>Created: {createdDate}</p>
              <p>Updated: {updatedDate}</p>
              <p>Completed: {isCompleted}</p>
              <button onClick={() => this.removeTask(this.state)}>REMOVE</button>
              <button onClick={() => this.updateTaskWindow(this.state)}>Update</button>
              <hr />
            </div>
          );
        }) ) : task.map(item => {
          const { title, description, createdDate, updatedDate, isCompleted } = item;
          return (
            <div style={{ width: '50%', margin: 'auto'}} key={title}>
              <input type="text" value={title}/>
              <p>Desc: {description}</p>
              <p>Created: {createdDate}</p>
              <p>Updated: {updatedDate}</p>
              <p>Completed: {isCompleted}</p>
              <button onClick={() => this.removeTask(this.state)}>Cancel</button>
              <button onClick={() => this.updateTaskWindow(this.state)}>Submit</button>
              <hr />
            </div>
          );
        }) 

      ) : (
        <h3>Loading...</h3>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  </div>
);
}
```

What is wrong in this case? I am totally out of any ideas. Been trying at this for the last 3 hours or so. I have a similar API call for removing task through DELETE request, everything is pretty much entirely the same, and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using promises, when finish making the first request it update the title state then return it make make the second request. i hope this is helpful.